# MoveIt MSA configuration files not as straight forward as they say?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been struggling introducing my custom .xacro into MoveIt.  I have followed the MSA to a T.

I attempted the Panda MoveIt tutorials first, and they work perfectly.

My robot already works in Rviz in conjunction with Joint State Publisher so I know it operates correctly in its range of motion.

I have also been able to manually boot it into an empty gazebo world.  I am just having trouble creating and utilizing the files that are generated from the MSA.

When I follow the instructions from https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html?highlight=moveit and attempt to "roslaunch moveit_config demo.launch" I get this response...

(I cannot post a screenshot without 5 points (?) so I C->P'd)

```
homefolder@ubuntu:~/manipulator_ws$ roslaunch version1_desc demo.launch
... logging to /home/homefolder/.ros/log/48303788-8948-11ea-a025-001c429fcd02/roslaunch-ubuntu-31411.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid <arg> tag: moveit_config
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/homefolder/manipulator_ws/src/ros-moveit-arm/moveit_plugin
ROS path [2]=/home/homefolder/manipulator_ws/src/moveit_tutorials
ROS path [3]=/home/homefolder/manipulator_ws/src/my-robotic-manipulator
ROS path [4]=/home/homefolder/manipulator_ws/src/ros-moveit-arm/my_arm_xacro
ROS path [5]=/home/homefolder/manipulator_ws/src/panda_moveit_config
ROS path [6]=/home/homefolder/manipulator_ws/src/version1_desc
ROS path [7]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share. 

Arg xml is <arg default="$(find moveit_config)/default_warehouse_mongo_db" name="db_path"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

The workspace is named "manipulator_ws." My main package is "version1_desc" and when I started the MSA, I opened the new package into this "version1_desc".  So the config files that the MSA has created are located in:

```
manipulator_ws/src/version1_desc/moveit_config/config
```

and

```
manipulator_ws/src/version1_desc/moveit_config/launch
```

I remember reading that creating a package inside a package usually brings up issues, so this part of the creation process confused me. As soon as the MSA created a package in a package, I assumed this would not work, and it didn't.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
ROS Kinetic
Using Parallels Desktop on a 2019 macbook pro

This seems like a path problem but I am new to the system.  I have seen other posts with similar issues but the solutions that have been deemed worthy of "closing" do not provide clear solutions to my issue.

Can anyone offer some assistance? I have spent the better part of 5 hours moving stuff around and erasing and recreating these moveit_config files to no luck.  Im about ready to quit and go be a construction worker again.

please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350854/moveit-msa-configuration-files-not-as-straight-forward-as-they-say?/) by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2020-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-28**:\

> (I cannot post a screenshot without 5 points (?) so I C->P'd)

Which is perfect, as there is no need to show a screenshot of an error message which is all text. It's also not allowed according to the support guidelines.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-28**:
Finally as a suggestion: change the title of your question. As-is, it does not convey anything about what sort of problem you encountered. This makes it almost useless, as people searching will not get any hint about the topic your question.

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-04-28**:
This is great advice, all round. Thank you sir. I will work on my formatting as far at the questions go and appreciate the timely help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-28**:
I re-opened your question, as it's unclear to me why you closed it as a duplicate.

If it really is a duplicate, please post a link to the Q&A it is a duplicate of here in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> manipulator_ws/src/version1_desc/moveit_config/launch
> ```
>
> I remember reading that creating a package inside a package usually brings up issues, so this part of the creation process confused me.

yes, this is your problem most likely.

Move the entire `moveit_config` directory (including all its contents) to `manipulator_ws/src`. Then delete the `build`, `devel` and `install` folders from your `manipulator_ws` (the last one only if it exists) and build your workspace again. Make sure to `source devel/setup.bash` after a successful build.

Now try again.

As to whether the MSA is "not as straight forward as they say?": in the end, it's the user which determines *where* the output of the MSA should be stored. If you direct it to generate the package *inside* another package, that's where the output will be generated.

I'm not entirely sure I understand why you did that, but that's not too important either.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1